# How can I make sure that clicking on an image would redirect me to my home page?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, let's say this is the code:

```
<a href="index.html">
<img src="http://oi40.tinypic.com/aes9wo.jpg">
</a>
```

I know clicking on it doesn't redirect you anywhere, but if it did, how would you ensure that instead of redirecting you there, it would redirect you somewhere else, where you say it should?

For example, assume the code is an iframe or anything that cannot be touched. What can be done to catch the link it's directing you onclick, and either deny it, or just make the clickable option "unclickable" altogether?

Would you do something like:

```
<div onclick="window.location='http://google.ca'()" style="cursor:pointer">
<a href="index.html">
<img src="http://oi40.tinypic.com/aes9wo.jpg">
</a>
<div>
```

Using `<div>` HTML tag or Javascript, AND ASSUMING YOU CANT AMEND THE CODE GIVEN

Please and thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to change where the `<a>` tag links? As in, changing the href attribute? Also, what would a `<div>` tag have to do with it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'redirect you anywhere'? Currently clicking on this link would direct the user to index.html. Do you mean you want it to appear as if the site is directing you somewhere but you want to link them somewhere else?

Comment: OP just didn't know that clicking on an image within a href would take you to the link. Hopefully they understand now.

Comment: No, no. Tom had it right. I updated the question

Comment: is the iframe in the same domain as the main page?

Comment: no, hypothetically, the iframe is provided by another host. so instead of clicking on the image/service provided by the website, and being directed to their website, i want it to direct to my main page, or do nothing; either way would work

Answer (score 2):

Just change:

```
<a href="index.html">
```

to:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
```

or anywhere else you like. http://example.com/your-site/

Does that make sense? Or do you need something more specific?

Comment: I mean, assuming you cant change the code. Sorry, should have been more clear!

Comment: Yeah, that makes a big difference. Could you update your questions and specify your situation a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Link to your full home page URL.

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com">
  <img src="http://oi40.tinypic.com/aes9wo.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: I mean, assuming you cant change the code. Sorry, should have been more clear!